# Flash power and softboxes — add a bounty or add a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently we've gotten a couple of questions which essentially reduce to [How many EV will a softbox knock down off your flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61011/how-many-ev-will-a-softbox-knock-down-off-your-flash) — but that doesn't really have great answers. I know it's not a simple answer (like "add 2 EV and there you go"), but it'd be nice to have some discussion of flash GN and what *might* be appropriate for example situations. Will a mid-range ~ GN 30 flash ever be useful with a softbox, or is more power basically required when using lighting modifiers?

I'm happy to add a bounty to the above question, but I could also see a new question asking something like "How powerful a flash do I need for use with a softbox in typical situations?"

Which do you think is better?

Answer (score 1):

Since it can vary so much from one light modifier to the next I'm not sure any such question is a good fit here unless a specific modifier is identified. It's kind of like asking, "How many horsepower does an engine need to accelerate a car from 0-60 mph in 6 seconds? Well, it depends on the weight of the car, the gearing in the drivetrain, the size of the tires, the aerodynamic coefficient of drag, etc.

Comment: Do you think it really needs to be a specific individual (well, line/model) of modifier, or would "medium-sized softbox designed for speedlight-style flashes" be close enough to give useful ballpark answers? (How many horsepower does it take for a typical four-door family sedan?)

Comment: There's still a pretty wide variation. And most softboxes have adjustable baffles that also affect how much light they eat. Does the car only contain a single driver or is it loaded down with four people and their luggage on the way for a two week vacation? The makers of most higher end softboxes will list a specification in stops of how much their product reduces the light in various orientations. The reason they do is because it is such a highly variable thing.